# retrieving value of an enumerated type in Z3Py

Tags: python, z3

How do I retrieve the values of an enumerated variable `v`  ? For example,

```
vTyp, (val1,val2,val3) = EnumSort('vTyp',['val1','val2','val3'])
v = Const('my variable',vTyp)
```

Now, given *just* the above variable `v`,  how would I retrieve a list of values  `[val1,val2,val3]` of `v` (where `val1,val3,val3` are expressions as above) ?

I have tried `[v.sort().constructor(0), ...(1), ...(2)]`  but the constructor method does not return an expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `v.sort().constructor(0)` returns a Z3 function declaration. In Z3, constants are functions with 0 arguments. To convert the declaration in a constant expression, we should use `v.sort().constructor(0)()`.

BTW, the function `is_func_decl` can be used to test whether an object is a Z3 function declaration or not. The function `is_expr` is the equivalent for Z3 expressions.

```
print is_func_decl(v.sort().constructor(0))
print is_expr(v.sort().constructor(0))
print is_expr(v.sort().constructor(0)())
```